# Testing - Generate xml files that do not conform a schema

Tags: unit-testing, xsd, code-generation

for testing purposes, I'd like to generate xml samples that do not conform to an existing schema.
I want this files to be used for unit testing.

I think they would permit :

- Detection of constructions a schema permits, though the writer didn't intent to.
- Detection of constructions a schema denies, though the writer wanted to enable them.
- Samples to test againts if the schema is being modified slightly in the future.

I found generators of valid samples, but not the contrary ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand first bullet point.

But are you looking for xml generators that will generate xml that is not compliant with schema!? I don't think you will find one.

Just generate good xml and then break it and save and use it as example of wrong xml.

Comment: I think you'r right about not finding a tool for this.
By the way though, schemas are complicated, and sometimes, you can't realize something you don't want is allowed (because sometimes, you don't even realize this particular issue could happen). You'll then not be able to alter consciously a valid file that will cover this particular feature.

I think it may seems side issues, but as I said in the first post, I think a tool could easyly produce a wide variety of counter-examples, that could point to some uncovered/unthought issue, etc ...